# How to match string if behind no matching pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need to get `text` from `> text` or `example > text` but I do not need to match string if it looks like `>> text`.

I tried it: `(?<!\<)>(.*)` but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by text? Did you mean a string `text`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, yes, I need to get any string after `>` symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would match all the characters which are just after to `>` but not after to `>>`,

```
(?:[^>]|^)> \K(?:(?!>>).)*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cN4tF8/3)